# Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.ArrayList' to 'java.util.ArrayList<java.io.File>' less... (Ctrl+F1)

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parcelable, badparcelableexception

I am retrieving file info from the another activity into my main activity.But I facing the Unchecked assignment problem.My code is as follows.Would anyone can tell me what to do to solve this problem.

```
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle b = i.getExtras();
    mysongs = (ArrayList) b.getParcelableArrayList("songlist");// This line shows this problem.
    int position = b.getInt("pos",0);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(mysongs.get(position).toString());
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),uri);
    mediaPlayer.start();
```

I tried this line by declaring it into globally.but the problem is I cann't set the bundel b into this(when i declare it globally).

Comment: how to set ArrayList "songList" in Activity? Why not use OnActivityOnResult?

Comment: What type of array is mysongs?

Comment: mysongs is  File type Arraylist...I am trying follwing code

ArrayList<File> mysongs= (ArrayList) b.getParcelableArrayList("songlist");

by writting it globally  but still show an error.

Comment: I set arrylist through an arrylist instance vaiable.....like

ArrayList<File> mysongs;

and then use  getIntent to get the bundle b .After that i Just store the mysongs using getparcelebelarraylist.

@ fechidal